# Python Dictionary multiple values per key

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through dictionary with multiple values assigned to a key. Like so:

```
devices =  {'device_ip':('10.1.1.1','10.1.1.2','10.1.1.3'),
        'device_hostname':('sw1','sw2','sw3')}
```

I'm then trying to pass IP and Hostname values into something like this:

```
scp_command = 'sshpass -p 123 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cisco@' + devices['device_ip'] + ':startup.cfg ' + devices['device_hostname'] + filename
```

What I don't want is to modify my `scp_command` for each IP/Hostname pair and re-use this variable to have least amount of lines in the code.

Comment: You should probably consider redesigning your data structure, since for your task a more direct approach seems more practical: `devices = {'sw1':'10.1.1.1', 'sw2':'10.1.1.2', ...}`

Comment: Ok, that is more logical. But how do i leave scp_command structure unchanged for each dict iteration as i try to run the command? Sorry for being a complete noob :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments, I would go for a different data structure:

```
devices = {'sw1':'10.1.1.1',
           'sw2':'10.1.1.2',
           'sw3':'10.1.1.3'}
```

To build your `scp_command` string, I suggest using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), e.g.:

```
scp_command = 'sshpass -p 123 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cisco@{ip}:startup.cfg {host} {file}'
cfg_file='example.cfg'
for device in devices:
    print(scp_command.format(ip=devices[device], host=device, file=cfg_file))
```

That way you can introduce placeholders `{}` in your string, which will be replaced by `.format()` with your current data. Result:

```
sshpass -p 123 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cisco@10.1.1.1:startup.cfg sw1 example.cfg
sshpass -p 123 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cisco@10.1.1.2:startup.cfg sw2 example.cfg
sshpass -p 123 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cisco@10.1.1.3:startup.cfg sw3 example.cfg
```

Comment: I've decided to use DarkKnight's method so that i don't have to run multiple scp commands and re-use it:
def initiate_backup():
    filename = ''
    rancid_location = '/var/lib/rancid/network/configs'
    for i in range(-1,len(devices)):
        move_cfg = 'mv ' + devices['device_hostname'][i] + ' ' + rancid_location + filename
        scp_cfg = 'sshpass -p 1 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cisco@' + devices['device_ip'][i] + ':startup.cfg ' + devices['device_hostname'][i] + filename

Only issue with that is dict key value changes as i add more devices so i need to work on my range

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning a `list` to each `key-value` pair?

```
devices =  {'device_ip':['10.1.1.1','10.1.1.2','10.1.1.3'],
    'device_hostname':['sw1','sw2','sw3']}
```

Acess them using: `devices['device_ip'][<index>]`